# Netlogo Agents error

Tags: netlogo

I am implementing an evacuation simulation of a lecture hall.And i have two types of students those who sit on tables and extra students who allocated randomly inside the class.So i created **two sliders** in order to allocate the students at the desired numbers.The sliders are named **extrastudents** and **standarstudents**. When the simulation starts i want all the students (both in tables and extras students) to go to the nearest exit ( i have two exits ) .So i implemented that for only the students that are seating down :

```
ask standarstudents  [
ifelse pycor > 0
[ set target one-of nexits]
[ set target one-of sexits]
face target
]
```

Nexits is the north exit.
Sexits is the south exit.

The problem is that i get this error and i can move on :

ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the number 3 instead.
error while observer running ASK.(The number 3 derives from the slider that user is pick)
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'

org.nlogo.nvm.ArgumentTypeException: ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the number 3 instead.

any ideas?

Comment: Also, I don't know if you are aware of this, but `pycor` reports the coordinates of the _patch_ that the turtle is on, which will be different from the coordinates that the _turtle_ is on if it's not at the center of a patch. A turtle whose `ycor` is `0.5` will have `pycor = 0` and thus `pycor > 0` will be false even if the turtle is slightly above the origin, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @NicolasPayette: A turtle whose ycor is 0.5 has a pycor of 1, not 0.

Comment: @SethTisue My mistake -- thanks for pointing it out. `0.5` is rounded up, so it was a bad example. A correct one would have been a `ycor` of `0.49`, which _will_ give a `pycor` of `0` (so the general point still stands...)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have *sliders* named `extrastudents` and `standarstudents`, those two variables are *numeric* values representing how many students of each kind you want, **not** the students themselves. Like the error message says, the `ask` primitive works with *agentsets* that represent "who you are asking".

Have you actually created your students? Putting sliders on the interface won't do anything by itself. I would suggest renaming your sliders to something like `num-extrastudents` and `num-standarstudents` and then using code like this to initialize your population:

```
breed [ extrastudents extrastudent ]
breed [ standarstudents standarstudent ]

to setup
  create-standarstudents num-standarstudents
  create-extrastudents num-extrastudents
end
```

Then, the code you have posted would work because `extrastudents` and `standarstudents` would be *breeds* of turtles, and thus, agentsets.